# Restful Rails Create Action Render with Nested Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site where a Ticket has many Replies

The URL for the page is /ticket/x/replies/new gotten to by

```
= link_to("Add a Reply", new_ticket_reply_url(@ticket))
```

This works great.
This of course goes to the Reply controller.  In the controller when there is an error on @reply.save we have

```
format.html {render :action => "new" }
```

This just calls new in the reply controller, without taking into consideration the ticket.
Can anyone explain (best practice) how to do the correct render on errors when using a nested route?

This is standard rails 3.2 generated code i'm trying to make work with my limited knowledge
Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling "save" in the "new" action? That would be a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

You'll do render the same way, but you need to get the ticket out of the params.

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
  @reply = Reply.new
end
```